# Multi-index Heatmap in Altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair

Is there a way to plot a heatmap that has a multi-index on the y-axis? Like the following, but in one single 4x4 grid instead of two facets:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    '1st_index': (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    'x': list(range(4))*4,
    '2nd_index': (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    'z': range(16)})
alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='2nd_index:O',
    color='z:Q',
    row='1st_index:O'
).configure_scale(
    bandPaddingInner=0.1
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a multi-index heatmap directly with the y encoding, but there are two ways you might approach this.

One possibility is to adjust the facet configurations so the facets appear as one chart. For example:

```python
alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y=alt.Y('2nd_index:O', title=None),
    color='z:Q',
    row=alt.Row('1st_index:O', title=None),
).configure_scale(
    bandPaddingInner=0.1
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a calculate transform to combine the fields and plot this instead:

```python
alt.Chart(source).transform_calculate(
    index = '(' + alt.datum['1st_index'] + "," + alt.datum['2nd_index'] + ')'
).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='index:N',
    color='z:Q',
).configure_scale(
    bandPaddingInner=0.1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! There's always a way to do it with Altair, I really love your library :-)